# How to implement a vector of any size in glsl

Tags: arrays, vector, struct, glsl, shader

Currently I'm trying to implement a math library for glsl, which will be useful later for the shader programs that I'm going to create. I've tried to start off simple and create a vector structure of size N, where the size does not change throughout the program.  For example, a vector could look like `kr_vec a = kr_vec(4, float(4)(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))` or it can even just have 2 components or more `kr_vec b = kr_vec(2, float(2)(1.0,2.0))`. I tried to write a struct for it

```
struct kr_vec {
    const int size;
    float elements[size];
};
```

However it doesn't work, I was hoping that there was maybe a template struct that I could use which would mean that I won't have to make a different struct for each data type array that I want to use.

```
template <typename in_type, const int in_length>
struct kr_vec {
    in_type elements[in_length];
};
```

I've done a bit of reading and I saw that it's possible with memory buffers, however, I don't know how to do it when you can call the function more than once.
If anyone can help me find a working piece of code that solves my issue that would be great, Thanks!

Comment: @Rabbid76 Is there any way that I can implement the feature that I want then?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Why not? It's possible to make an array with any size you want so why cant I do this in a struct?

Comment: @Rabbid76 With the struct that im using, it is constant but it still returns an error

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible in [GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)).

---

First, let's look at the construct in your question:

> ```c
> struct kr_vec {
>    const int size;
>    float elements[size];
> };
> ```

This is not possible for several reasons:

In GLSL you can make an array of any size. However see [Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML) - 4.1.9 Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#basic-types):

> When an array size is specified in a declaration, it must be an integral constant expression [...]

The element of a `struct` can't be `const`. `const` is a [Storage Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#storage-qualifiers) for a variable (or a [Parameter Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#parameter-qualifiers)) and cannot be used on the element of a structure. And of course constants have to be initialized.

You can specify the array size with a constant, but that's obviously not what you want:

```c
const int size = 4;

struct kr_vec {
    float elements[size];
};
```

---

> I was hoping that there was maybe a template struct that I could use [...]

No there is not. See the latest [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html).
In GLSL there is no concept for templates or generics.

---

> I've done a bit of reading and I saw that it's possible with memory buffers, [...]

No it is not. The only possibility for a variable sized array is the bottommost variable in the block definition of a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). However a SSBO is an [Interface](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)) for providing data for the shader program. It is not a function argument type.

---

The closest solution you can get in GLSL is the [Preprocessor](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#preprocessor). Write C like macros using `#define`, `#ifdef`, `else` etc.
Alternatively you can generate the shader code dynamically. Just concatenate snippets of code (strings) before compiling them.

---

Another possible solution is function overloading. You can declare multiple functions with the same name but different arguments (see [6.1. Function Definitions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#function-definitions)):

```c
void foo(float[3] v) { }

void foo(float[4] v) { }

void main(void)
{
    float[3] a;
    foo(a);

    float[4] b;
    foo(b);

    // [...]
}
```